# IS NULL condition in the predicate on Distributed Query does not run remote

Tags: sql-server

I am executing the below distributed query with predicate condition but it is not executing the code completely remote.

This is happening only for IS NULL predicate on BIT column

```
Select * from [RemoteServer].[DBName].dbo.[TableName] where [column] is null
```

The distributed server in this case is SQL Server and the Column is BIT data type.

For this, the remote query is pulling all the data back to the main server and then applying the filter. The execution plan look like this..

[image]

This only happens if I check for Is null condition. If I do, [column]=1 or Column=0, then the query runs remotely.

Comment: `EXEC RemoteServer.DBName.sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName WHERE [column] IS NULL;';`

Comment: Thanks for comment Aaron. I am more interested in knowing why it behaves this way for IS Null check on BIT data type. And without rewriting the code is there anything we can do to let the query run fully remote.

Comment: There's probably a lot of nuance in there, but if you want a query to run fully remote, then using sp_executesql is one way to force it.